# What are these stacked bulbs taking over my garden?

Tags: identification, weed-control, bulbs

There are a lot these bulbs so I don't know how I'm going to get them all out to grow anything else. I am in south-east England. Are they weeds or are all bulbous flowers? If it turns out they are flowers, could I just grow other stuff along side them? Or if they are weeds how do I remove them? I'm too impatient to wait to see what they grow into because I want to get planting stuff as soon as possible so any information would be great!

[image]

[image]

[image][image][image]

Comment: Yes, bulbs can be invasive and from the picture it looks like this is the case, but I don't know the name of the plant. Hopefully someone with greater knowledge will reconize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The green growth in the last picture is unrelated to the corms you've found - they are Crocosmia, a flowering plant with narrow, swordlike leaves, and this string type arrangement as they multiply is typical. If you want to replant some, do not separate the strings, plant them as they are.

It's impossible to know whether the corms are Crocosmia masonorum, the basic, short stemmed orange flowered type that grow wild down in Cornwall and Devon, or whether they are one of the newer, taller and more attractive  hybrids such as Crocosmia 'Lucifer', which is also known to be invasive in some soils. I suggest you dig them all out, then put a few in a deep pot in potting soil and wait and see what develops when they flower around June or July. If you like them, you can replant once you know what they are. There's no point in keeping all the corms, there will be far too many anyway, and if you decide to keep the ones you've put in a pot and replant, they will multiply all over again over time.

Comment: @pnuts Nope, I'm not  sure it is - need an unblurry picture  and taken in a week or so to be sure what it is... it's reminding of something, but not ground elder at this stage

Comment: I think you are right that the corms are crocosmia - I have added some photos of plants nearby that I'm guessing are the crocosmia all grown up? I will leave them in the ground then because I think they will fit in with my tropical look I'm hoping to eventually create.

Comment: I've also added a photo of a leaf of the green plant I found nearby that looks more mature. I'm fairly sure now that it is the dreaded ground elder. I read that it is edible so I've even had a tiny nibble lol and it does indeed taste like parsley. I'm just going to dig it out every time I see it pop up and hopefully other plants will take over. Thank you ever so much for all your help. I never would have worked it out on my own!

Comment: The second pic you added is, as you say, ground elder. If you're only renting where you live, then just keep digging it out - if its somewhere you own, then dealing with it more permanently would be better.

Comment: i'm not sure the green clump of leaves at the base of that tree or shrub is actually Crocosmia, more likely the leaves left behind from some other bulb, its a bit early for them to be up  that high. If it is crocosmia, its the boring, highly invasive, wild kind.

Answer (score 2):

the second from last photo , the plant at the base of a tree is "Hemerocallis" easy one to dig up and remove- as far as the others- the rest are correctly identified. good luck getting rid of the ground elder!